# JwksClient getSigningKey Error: socket hang up

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jwt, azure-web-app-service

### Im currently using jsonwebtoken and jwks-rsa for validating token got from request header. Below code will work perfect in local.

const client = jwksClient({
strictSsl: true, // Default value
jwksUri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys',
requestHeaders: {}, // Optional
requestAgentOptions: {}, // Optional
});

var signkey = await client.getSigningKey(kid);

---

But when i deploy same code in azure app service i get result as undefined and below error

2023-11-30T06:32:04.589091676Z Error: socket hang up
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589151480Z     at connResetException (node:internal/errors:720:14)
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589163380Z     at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:474:25)
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589171781Z     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589179781Z     at node:net:323:12
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589187582Z     at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:588:7) {
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589195582Z   code: 'ECONNRESET'
2023-11-30T06:32:04.589203383Z }

I tried microsoft jwks urls with tenant_id, app_id. But same error. Im wondering how it is working in local and why not in azure app service.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot with the following steps.

1. Check the Api endpoint you have defined in your front-end. Since it worked for you in the local system, maybe it's still the `http://localhost:8080/api/...` local endpoint defined in your code. So, change the endpoint to that of your azure service.
2. If you used require('http') to consume the https service and it showed "socket hang up". Then change require('http') to require('https') instead.(Port 443 is for HTTPS connections and port 80 is for HTTP connections)
3. Sometimes the request send from client side times out. Hence the "socket hang up" error is raised and you have to implement a `try/catch` block.
4. Check the web socket protocol used, if you used `ws://` (use if server is not secure) protocol instead of `wss://` (use if server is secure).
5. Check if the api path is prefixed with `/`. Ex: /api/users (correct) and api/users (incorrect).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello thanks for the suggestions. But none of this is creating the problem. Because same code has been deployed into azure app service few months back. We are trying to deploy same code in different app service and getting this error